# Mock sy-uname in ABAP Unit test

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, abap

I am trying to write my first unit tests in ABAP.

My method under test fetches team members of the logged-on user (via system variable `sy-uname`).

Since I want the test to run for everyone I can't just let the method run and assert one of my own team members.

I want to mock `sy-uname`, so the test is not dependent on who is executing it.

Is this possible? If yes how do you mock system parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to mock system parameters as far as i know. there are two ways to achieve this.

1.[TEST-SEAM/TEST-INJECTION](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abentest_seams.htm)

```
TEST-SEAM sy_uname.
   DATA(lv_uname) = sy-uname.
END-TEST-SEAM.  
"other code
```

Your unit test:

```
TEST-INJECTION y_uname.
   lv_name = "my_mock_user".
END-TEST-INJECTION.
```

2.Test Double

Define a interface

```
INTERFACE if_user

  METHODS get_uname
    RETURNING 
     VALUE(rv_uname) TYYPE syst_uname.

ENDINTERFACE.
```

In your production code, you create a CLASS to implement this interface and 
in the `get_uname` to return `sy-uname`.

somewhere in your code, you need to provide a SET method to be able to set the instance of IF_USER like below, and in the production code you call the instance of `if_user~get_uname` to get the user name.

```
METHODS set_user_provider
  IMPORTING 
    !io_user_provider TYPE REF TO if_user.
```

In your unit test code, you create a local CLASS to implement this interface and
in the get_uname to return your mock user.

```
CLASS lcl_mock_user_provider DEFINITION FOR TESTING. 
   PUBLIC SECTION.
     INTERFACES if_user.
ENDCLASS. 

CLASS lcl_mock_user_provider IMPLEMENTATION.
   METHOD if_user~get_uname.
     "return your mock user name. 
   ENDMETHOD. 
ENDCLASS.
```

your unit test code:

```
DATA(lo_mock_user_provider) = NEW lcl_mock_user_provider( ).

MyClassInstance.set_user_provider( lo_mock_user_provider ).
```

Comment: According to me, you should not propose test seams, and even less as a first solution. Anyway it's not really valid of using it for just mocking `SY-UNAME`.

Comment: TEST SEAM is a quick and working solution. Why not valid? According to what SAP documentation that it should not be used???

Comment: test seams seem to be the least invasive way to fix this problem, tbh. If there are reasons not to use it please tell @SandraRossi

Comment: @erch Answer added.

Comment: @Haojie If you split your two answers, I would vote for the one about the provider class, and downvote the one concerning the test seam ;-)

Comment: @SandraRossi Thanks! Like i said,  TEST-SEAM is a workable solution. sometimes solution is not like best practice ( you see it as a not very good practice , I understand that) . sometimes you have to list all the solutions you have. TEST-SEAM is definitely a quick and workable solution even when you have legacy code. the situation is that we don't have all the OO programming paradigm in the system.  it is definitely the decision that erch have to make whether he wants to add interface which means refactor of code or not.

Answer (score 5):

I half agree with the answers given by Haojie: one should **not** use [Test Seams (exist since ABAP 7.50)](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abentest_seams.htm) for a so simple case (replacing `sy-uname`), you should only use a provider class as he proposed.

Test seams are considered like a **pollution** of the productive code, because it reduces the readability of the code (mix of productive and test code).

NB: the ABAP documentation of test seams (link above) gives at least the following possible usages:

- Authorization checks (AUTHORITY-CHECK)
- ABAP SQL statements (SELECT, MODIFY, etc.) - It became a bad example since ABAP SQL can be mocked with the ABAP 7.52 class `CL_OSQL_TEST_ENVIRONMENT`.

As a rule-of-thumb, test seams should not be used at all, or considered as a solution of very last resort.

BUT if there's no other choice, like adding tests to a "legacy" code (old-badly-written code, usually not written using object-oriented design patterns, that is considered not testable via ABAP Unit), then you may have eventually no other choice.

As stated by [Horst Keller (one of best ABAP experts in the world and responsible of ABAP documentation at SAP)](https://blogs.sap.com/2015/10/23/abap-news-for-750-test-seams-and-injections):

> "If you cannot redesign and rewrite the whole application, as a workaround you make the code test dependent. This is regarded as bad style, but it helps."

As the question is only about `sy-uname` and it's not about the whole program, so the effort to refactor `sy-uname` is much lesser, so there's no excuse to not using a class.

Comment: A mandatory super() call in ABAP OO is the only reason I am aware to use TEST-SEAMS of when writing unit tests in modern ABAP code.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to replace just one system variable I would go for test seams.

Encapsulating system variables by an interface, requires caller to instantiate the class, maybe to pass the instance over multiple methods as parameter. This causes an increased complexity and decline of performance. This might be justified if there are scenarios with the need of other values than the system variable.

Test seams decrease readability of your productive code and thus might be regarded as pollution of the source code. One however needs to consider if a need of additional parameters introduces not even more noise.